# Appending HTML to UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to append some HTML to a `UIWebView`. It doesn't work and instead overwrites the existing HTML, since `oldHTML` below is always empty. The HTML string starts off as

```
<html><font color="0x0000FF">Blue text</font></html>
```

Code:

```
NSString *oldHTML = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerHTML"];

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", @"<html>", oldHTML, htmlToAdd, @"</html>"];

[myWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

So my questions are:

1. Is it even possible to get the html from a `UIWebView`?
2. If so, why does the first line fail/what is the correct method?
3. Is there a better way to append HTML to a `UIWebView`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect at the point you're trying to get the old html, your page hasn't completed loading yet, which is why it's returning a blank string.

Try creating and assigning a `UIWebViewDelegate` for your view that implements `webViewDidFinishLoad:` and putting your code above in that function - oldHTML should be non-blank at that point.

As for a better way, you can inject the content via javascript with something like this:

```
NSString *injectSrc = @"var i = document.createElement('div'); i.innerHTML = '%@';document.documentElement.appendChild(i);";
NSString *runToInject = [NSString stringWithFormat:injectSrc, @"Hello World"];
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:runToInject];
```

I'd recommend cleaning this up a bit, as it's not totally secure, but it should get the idea across of using javascript to inject new elements onto the page.